# App custom notification light color

Tags: android

I am programming my own app and I have some issues with my notifications.

Is it possible to have custom notification light color in android?
Because when I try to set the color to `#FF64B5F6` I didn't gte this color.
Or can I only set the color to these `Color.RED`, `Color.MAGENTA`?
And when I can set custom colors, is this the right way?

Java:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context).setLights(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, R.color.c_account), 500, 500)
```

xml:

```
<color name="c_account">#FF512DA8</color>
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have custom notification light color in android?

Well, you can try. It may not work.

First, some devices do not have an LED.

Of those that do, some devices do not use the LED for showing notifications.

Of those that do, some devices do not support different colors.

Of those that do, some devices will not support arbitrary colors (though ideally they map your requested color to one that they do support).

So, you are welcome to request a specific color. Just bear in mind that it is quite likely that you will not get the color that you want, and that there is no guarantee that you will get any sort of LED effect.